# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x" : Pydev configuration correct?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, installation, pydev

Really struggling with Eclipse Pydev, first time trying it out.

Trying to run shell command in python django, however I'm getting the following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rango'

I checked *Project > Properties  > PyDev - Django* to see settings module and both fields saying: "settings / manage module not found...

Here is the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/006pG.jpg

Here is the stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\CAB302\java-latest-released\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_6.4.1.201806231219\pysrc\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rango'
```

**Is the Python Path correct? Also**

I am not sure what a python path represent? (please explain). For reference
Python path screen capture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is9Xc.jpg

What would be the correct path for the error in the photo one? I assume its why I am getting the **ModuleNotFoundError**?

Please help!

Comment: What's the line that you're typing into the pydev console that's causing the `ModuleNotFoundError`?  It looks like `from rango...` -- it's hard to tell from the screenshot but it looks like `rango` is a submodule inside the `Tango` module.  If so, then you'd `from Tango.rango import ...`

Comment: Command is: from rango.models import user_session rango is the app, the folder structure is in the photo here, (blue lined) and the console: https://imgur.com/a/S3UnQic

Comment: If you look at the first photo in the question, pydev settings module field says not found? Any reason why?

Comment: `rango` is a submodule inside `Tango` -- you'll probably want to import it that way (as suggested above).

Comment: @jedwards Okay so I have a different error at the moment, I am trying to make migrations and I am getting this https://imgur.com/a/gN62vtB  "rango.settigns" not found?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/rNqXLqf the configuration in the pyDev seem wrong, whats the fix? ideas please

Comment: The first field from the image in my last comment is error free when I changed to "Tango/manage.py"  -- but the settings module field is still saying not found?

Comment: As shown here: https://imgur.com/a/I7bsfdV

Comment: Pleasee help new to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your PYTHONPATH configuration is pointing to the wrong place.

i.e.: if you want to `import rango`, you need to set `Project/Tango` (from your screenshot) as the source folder (which is the folder to be added to the PYTHONPATH).

This is in the `project properties -> PyDev - PYTHONPATH` (make sure you also unset the project root from the PYTHONPATH). See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html for details.

In the django settings, you should remove the `Project/` and `Project/Tango` -- the manage.py should be `Tango/manage.py` and the django settings module should be `Tango.settings`.